# Working with a string in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a long string in JSON format. This is what it looks like:

```
{"ShowMapUrl":true,"GameDiffusionType":5,"InputYellowCards":false,"DisplayYellowCards":false,"InputYellowCards2":false}
```

Note that the string is much longer. I've been trying to convert that string into a dictionary by using json.NET without success. Any tips?

Comment: Json is not a format.  It is serialized object data.   You cant deserialzie part of a json string, so you should post it all as well as how you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>()`:

```
var json = @"{""ShowMapUrl"":true,""GameDiffusionType"":5,""InputYellowCards"":false,""DisplayYellowCards"":false,""InputYellowCards2"":false}";
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Comment: It works with the string you used, but not with mine. But why do you have more quotes than I do? What does the symbol @ do?

Comment: @DwightShrout - [2.4.4.5 String literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx).